# FilePropPageDlgProc never executes "case WM_INITDIALOG:" in windows 10

Tags: c++, windows, callback, windows-shell

I am using `IShellPropSheetExt::AddPages()` method to add one more property page. In Windows 7, Windows Server 12 R2, the added property page is displayed properly. But in Windows 10, when I click on the added property tab, it disappears.

This is happening because everytime `FilePropPageDlgProc()` is called, the `uMsg` parameter never matches `WM_INITDIALOG`.  So no dialogue is created. And after a few calls to `FilePropPageDlgProc()`, `FilePropPageCallbackProc()` is executed which returns false.

```
    BOOL CALLBACK FilePropPageDlgProc ( HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
       {
           switch (uMsg)
           {
               case WM_INITDIALOG:
                {
                    /*code to initialise dialogue box*/
                    /*This case is never executed in windows 10. In other win7, win12 it is executed properly*/
                }
            }
        }

        UINT CALLBACK FilePropPageCallbackProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, LPPROPSHEETPAGE ppsp)
        {
            switch(uMsg)
            {
                ...
                case PSPCB_RELEASE:
                {
                   FilePropSheetExt *pExt = reinterpret_cast<FilePropSheetExt *>(ppsp->lParam);
                   if (pExt != NULL)
                   {
                     pExt->Release();
                   }
                }
                break;
            }
          return FALSE;
      }
      HRESULT AddPages(LPFNADDPROPSHEETPAGE lpfnAddPage, LPARAM lParam)
      {
              PROPSHEETPAGE  propsp = {0};
              HPROPSHEETPAGE hproppage;
              propsp.dwSize = sizeof(propsp);
              propsp.dwFlags = PSP_USEREFPARENT | PSP_USETITLE | PSP_USECALLBACK;
              propsp.hInstance = NULL;
              propsp.pfnDlgProc = (DLGPROC)FilePropPageDlgProc;
              propsp.pcRefParent = (UINT*)&g_cRefModule;
              propsp.pfnCallback = FilePropPageCallbackProc;
              propsp.lParam = (LPARAM)this;
              hproppage = CreatePropertySheetPage(&propsp);
              if (pfnAddPage(hproppage, lParam))
              {
                  this->AddRef();
                  return S_OK;
              }
              else
                 DestroyPropertySheetPage(hproppage);                  }

      }
```

I am not understanding from where `FilePropPageDlgProc` is getting called repeatedly, from where `uMsg` parameter value is assigned, and why this value is not matching `WM_INITDIALOG`.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] showing how you are using `AddPages()` and hooking up `FilePropPageDlgProc` and `FilePropPageCallbackProc` to the pages.

Comment: added, I am using https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CppShellExtPropSheetHandler-d93b49b7 for reference. but I am not getting from where uMsg value is assigned and FileproppageDlgProc is called repeatedly.

Comment: This means that the dialog box failed to be created. For example, maybe it uses a custom control that hasn't been registered.

Comment: when I click on properties option of file/folder, PropPageCallbackProc() is called and I can see General properties of that file/folder. when I click on my newly added property tab PropPageDlgProc() is executed repeatedly, everytime with different uMsg value. that uMsg value never matches with WM_INITDIALOG. I need to know from where PropPageDlgProc() is called repeatedly, and how different uMsg parameter value is passed to PropPageDlgProc() everytime.

Comment: @NehaJoshi what `uMsg` values DOES `FilePropPageDlgProc()` actually receive? Also, the code you showed is missing a `return` statement.

Comment: Crystal ball says that you moved from a 32-bit version of Win7 to the 64-bit version of Win10.  Now that (DLGPROC) cast you used to stop the compiler from telling you that you were doing it wrong starts to matter.  The return type of FilePropPageDlgProc must be INT_PTR, not BOOL.